# Transforming date + time in a TimeStamp Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having some trouble with making a timestamp from a date and a time

What i'm trying to do:

```
date = "2016 2 21"
time = "03:00 UTC"
output = "Thu, 21 Feb 2016 03:00:00 UTC +00:00"
```

I'm getting the date from a form_for:

```
f.date_field(:date_first)
```

But I'm not sure of how should I pick up the time.

Comment: Considering that the 21st was a Sunday, you may have some trouble getting `output`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you a headstart:

```
dt = "2016-2-21"
time = "03:00 UTC"
dtime = DateTime.parse(dt + 'T' + time)
output = dtime.rfc2822
```

and the result is:

```
#=> "Sun, 21 Feb 2016 03:00:00 +0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this

```
strftime("%d.%m.%Y.  %H:%M:%S")
```

and also get your locale yml file from here
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Comment: Using `strftime` is a good idea, but you need it to be a complete, executable statement. I suggest you also include `require 'time'` and show the return value.